# How to start Phoenix by using PostgreSQL through container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, phoenix-framework

I tried:

```
$ alias psql="docker exec -ti pg-hello-phoenix sh -c 'exec psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres'"
$ mix ecto.create
```

but got:

> ** (RuntimeError) could not find executable `psql` in path, please guarantee it is available before running ecto commands
>       lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:106: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.run_with_psql/2
>       lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:83: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.storage_up/1
>       lib/mix/tasks/ecto.create.ex:34: anonymous fn/2 in Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Create.run/1
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:604: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:604: Enum.each/2
>       (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
>       (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2

Also I tried to create symlink `/usr/local/bin/psql`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker exec -ti pg-hello-phoenix sh -c "exec psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres $@"
```

and then:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/psql
```

check:

```
$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.1
```

run again:

```
$ mix ecto.create
** (Mix) The database for HelloPhoenix.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: cannot enable tty mode on non tty input
.
```

Container with PostgreSQL is launched:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
013464d7227e        postgres            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   47 minutes ago      Up 47 minutes       5432/tcp            pg-hello-phoenix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me I did the following:

```
sudo docker exec -it postgres-db bash
```

After I got the interactive shell

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
```

Then I create my db manually:

```
CREATE DATABASE cars_dev;
```

Then finally:

```
mix ecto.migrate
```

Everything worked fine after that :) hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by going into /config/.exs  In my case it was development, so /config/dev.exs and left the hostname as localhost but added another setting for port: 32768  because that's the port that docker exposed.

Make sure to put a space between the port: and the number (not string). Otherwise it won't work.

Worked as usual after that. The natural assumption is that the username / password matches on the container as well.